# Route53 + Elastic Load Balancer not responding, but individual instances are working

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, dns

This is a confusing situation but let me try my level best to present my problem.

I am trying my hand at setting up an aws app architecture by following this blueprint: https://s3.amazonaws.com/awsmedia/architecturecenter/AWS_ac_ra_web_01.pdf

I don't require the web server part of it, so the components that I am trying to set up are Route53 -> Elastic Load Balancer -> (A subnet containing two ec2 instances that contain my nodejs app)

I have created a hosted zone on Route53, and I created a set record with an alias set to the ELB.

At first, I did not setup NGINX on my EC2 instances and in my ELB configuration I registered my EC2 instances on the port on which the application runs, i.e 9000. At this point, if I tried to access my app via the domain name, the page was unreachable, and I tried to access it via the ELB DNS, it returned with 504.

Then I set up Nginx on my instances and registered instances on ELB with port 80, and this time ELB returned with 503, however the page is still unreachable via Route53

I am using an application load balancer with HTTPS protocol.

So, at this point, I can't access my app via Route53, and I am getting 503 when I access it via ELB DNS, however, if I point my browser to the public dns of either of my ec2 instances, I am getting response from my APIs.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Thanks a lot. The supportive resource help me get an good idea of your environment. I'm also new to the AWS world, so sorry if I'm asking any dumb question.

Comment: Are you using elastic IP address? for your ec2 instances? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html

Comment: The ELB shows the instances as **healthy**?

Comment: @MichaelAbabio I redid the whole process and made a few changes and it worked, although it is still quite raw. I first issued a new wildcard SSL certificate from ACM for my domain, since I'd be hosting my apis on a subdomain. Then I attached elastic ips to my instances. Now, I need to figure out whether or not I need NGINX, and if I do, then do I need to make it listen on port 443 too.

Comment: Progress, great!

Comment: @relentless-coder how's it going?

Comment: @MichaelAbabio Hey, yeah, well, I am stuck on a different issue now. I can't make socket.io work with my setup. Have been digging up on that for the past 3 days